# How to optimise AWS DocumentDB performances

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I have a DocumentDB cluster with a single instance that is mainly used by a node.js application. I need to run a simple query across a collection, which is linked to two other collections. This query is going to return a lor of results, let's say from 80.000 to 600.000 documents. Then the node application will serialize the necessary information to return to the client. Then the client can apply filters to this data for his analysys.

The request tooks approx 30 seconds: 28 sec waiting to the server and <2 sec content download. I would like to understand if this is due to the fact that my instance is just 4 GB and 2 vCPU, or if there's some bottleneck when trasferring data from DocumentDB and EC2.

Or should I just try to optimize how I save data to this collection, trying to get rid of other collection relations? Or should I just move to a model where I make an API call and a query every time the client changes filters client side?

thanks for any suggestion

Comment: This question feels too broad and opinion based to be good for the site. Generally though I'd say that sending the client _all_ of the data and then having filtering applied client side may not be a good approach. Typically you'd want to allow the database to efficiently retrieve just the data that the client is interested in which it can do by using indexes etc

Comment: Please show us some sample data and your queries and the indexes you created.

Comment: @user20042973 the idea would be that if the browser already downloaded all the data, then filter it requires no time. I am ok to spend 2 sec for the download, I don't understand if it is normal the query to take 28 sec. If I run the same query from compass with profiler enabled on documentDB, it takes 47ms, why from EC2 is taking so long? When I call documentDB from EC2 for some reason the profiler is not logging anything.

Comment: Can you execute the query, from EC2, with .explain("executionStats") and post the output here?